# Binds not working on a specific part

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, key-bindings

So earlier in my program, I use the line

```
l.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e: getSide(i))
```

and when I click on the element, it works fine.

However, later I use the line

```
l.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e: sortby(x))
```

for a different local object. 
`getSide` is a stub that prints the value of `i` defined when binding. `sortby` is a Quicksort that (for debugging purposes) prints the value of `x` at the start. The curious thing is that while `getSide` returns the correct value, `sortby` does not.

`getSide` returns `i`, whereas `sortby` prints `len(column)-1`, i.e the last Label to be bound.

Comment: That link to the code will likely be out of date very soon as you check in more code. That will make this question impossible to understand in the future. If you're going to link to code in github, make sure you link to a very specific revision.

Comment: It's alright, as iCodez has provided the answer.

Comment: it's not really alright, because we want questions and answers to stand the test of time, so others can benefit from the collective knowledge.

Comment: The code is self contained. Turns out that it's not something I did before that line, but the line itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating these bindings inside a loop.  When you do this, you must "capture" any values you use inside a lambda function in its argument list:

```
for x in range(0,len(columns)):
...
    l.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e, x=x: sortby(x))
#                                 ^^^
```

This is because the expression contained inside a lambda function is evaluated at call-time, not definition-time.  So, the `x` in `sortby(x)` will always refer to the last value held by `x` in the loop.

Default arguments however are evaluated at definition-time.  Thus, doing `x=x` ensures that `x` refers to the current value of `x` inside the loop.

Comment: I confirmed that this fixes the issue. Nice job! I was completely stumped on this one.

Comment: It's a really sneaky error. My preference in general is to define a short function instead of using lambda.

Comment: It's a weird thing when it had worked in all prior situations, but not for one specific. I'll remember this for future.