# Make a button's command cause the button's text to be inserted into an entry

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm creating a series of buttons, each with different text. I  would like to, upon clicking a button, retrieve its corresponding text and insert that text into an Entry. The best I can get is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

root= tk.Tk()
entry= tk.Entry(root)
def callback():
    entry.insert(0, data)

for i in range(20):
    data= str(randint(0,100))
    button = tk.Button(root, text = data, command=callback).pack()
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

which causes the entry to be set as the last button's text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do two things:

1. Make your `callback` function accept an argument that will be the button's text:

   ```
   def callback(text):
       entry.insert(0, text)
   ```
2. Assign each button's `command` option to a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-lambda_expr) that sends this text to `callback`:

   ```
   command=lambda data=data: callback(data)
   ```

Below is what the complete code will look like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

root= tk.Tk()
entry= tk.Entry(root)
def callback(text):
    entry.insert(0, text)

for i in range(20):
    data= str(randint(0,100))
    tk.Button(root, text=data, command=lambda data=data: callback(data)).pack()
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps a lot! I've always ran into this site when googling programming issues and i couldn't find an answer to this one, so I figured I would make an account and am very pleased with the results.

I'll make sure to look more into what "lambda" does. I've seen it before, but never understood it.

Comment: Happy to have been of help!  And the lambda is not anything special.  It is basically an in-line function.  You could get the same with `def func(data=data): callback(data)` and then `command=func`.  You need the `data=data` though in order to capture the value of `data` for each iteration.  See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26942110/2555451